# textview underline(secondary text)

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

How to create a secondary line(underline) in TextView?

For example

line1:

```
 |word1      word2       word3 word4|   //size17

 |      word2 description           |   //size 6
```

line2:

```
 |word4 word5 word6      word7      |   //size17

 |                word7 description |   //size6
```

**EDIT 27.05:**

preview version. How to improve?

```
public class DescriptionSpan extends ReplacementSpan {


String description;
Paint descriptionPaint;

public DescriptionSpan(Paint paint, String description) {
    descriptionPaint = paint;
    this.description = description;
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {

    float delta = getShift(paint, text.subSequence(start, end).toString(), description);

    if (delta >= 0) {
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
        canvas.drawText(description, 0, description.length(), x + delta, y + descriptionPaint.getTextSize(), descriptionPaint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x - delta, y, paint);
        canvas.drawText(description, 0, description.length(), x, y + descriptionPaint.getTextSize(), descriptionPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    return (int) Math.max(paint.measureText(text, start, end), descriptionPaint.measureText(description));
}


private float getShift(Paint paint, String text, String description) {
    return (paint.measureText(text) - descriptionPaint.measureText(description)) / 2;
}
```

Comment: I guessing you don't mean that this is a grid of texts, you mean that these are words within lines of a paragraph, and at a designated word, you want some secondary text under that word.  Is that accurate?  Maybe you could say some more about what you're doing with this text display.

Comment: yes. Basically need description around(top or bottom) word

Comment: This would require a custom Span subclass at the very least.  I will take a look at this.  If someone gave this to me to code, I'd consider writing a custom view and do all the text measurement/calculations/rendering directly.

Comment: I thought about it too. Seems solution have a lot of cases (especially for long description). I was hoping to find a ready class :) The task is not urgent. If I do not find it, I will write on Monday :)

Comment: @krislarson Oh, easy. I thought for implementation need more codes. ReplacementSpan have all that I need (**draw**; and **getSize**). Few minutes for basic implementation :)

Comment: @krislarson please review code ;) I don't know rules for spans

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like writing answers without code; however, I've spent way too long on this (I can't resist a challenge when it comes to coding) and I think I have enough information to put you in the right direction without a working code sample.

The way it's *supposed* to work is that in `getSize()` you would set the `FontMetricsInt` that are passed in to the proper heights for your span, as well as return the span width.

But here's the thing: The only concrete implementation of `ReplacementSpan` is `ImageSpan` which extends `DynamicDrawableSpan` (which is a `ReplacementSpan`).  If you look at `DynamicDrawableSpan`, it sets the descent and bottom to zero and the ascent and top to the size of the drawable.  More on this in a second.

When I took your code and tried to add the font metrics logic to `getSize()`, I ran into a couple problems.

1. Changes in ascent/top are honored, but any change to the bottom -- which would need to the adjusted to allow room for your description -- is *not* honored.  It seems that the logic is tailored to accommodate `ImageSpan`/`DynamicDrawableSpan`, and everything else is treated as an untested corner case.
2. `ReplacementSpan` seems to be targeted for single-line texts. The ascent & top are correctly set up in the first paragraph line, but after the line wraps, the normal ascent/top are restored.
3. The span is generally treated as a non-breaking word, but I did run into an intermittent bug where the span itself was wrapped onto a second line.  Obviously this would be a problem with calculating where to put all your texts.

So if you really wanted to do this with spans, I think what you would have to do is have another custom paragraph-style span that implements `LineHeightSpan`.  For this you would implement `chooseHeight()`.  How this works is that `chooseHeight()` would be called for each line in the paragraph.  Your implementation would look for a `DescriptionSpan` on that line and set the font metrics to accommodate the description text.  So you would wrap each paragraph that had `DescriptionSpan`s with this paragraph-style span.  With this span, your `DescriptionSpan` wouldn't alter the font metrics in `getSize()`, and you'd just assume you have space for the description text in `draw()`.  (I hope the canvas isn't clipped to the span bounds.  That custom view idea just keeps looking better and better.)

I would love to get the code working and post it, but I spend too much time banging my head on `ReplacementSpan` font metrics.

Comment: Yeah, I know. In free time I will try to expand this solution. For current task it's enough (word/translation not take up a lot of space, additional space by lineSpacingMultiplier). I don't want to use custome view.  I think it will be enough to add something like [numberLine = measure/lineLenght +1 ;FontMetricsInt.bottom*numberLine; foreach draw line ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SpannableStringBuilder for this. Something like below :

```
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    span.append("First Line");
    span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.8f),0,firstLineLength);
    span.append("Second Line");
    span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1f),firstLineLength,firstLineLength+secondLineLength);
textView.setText(span);
```

Comment: Currently solution created text like cCcCcCcC. Calculate position for descriptio  looks hard for different multiline text.